# Laravel create model outside app namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-artisan

I want to use the command `php artisan make:model User` for creating an user inside the domain folder. Nevertheless it will end up in the App folder.

I've already tried this:

- `php artisan make:model Domain\User`
- `php artisan make:model Domain\\User`
- `php artisan make:model \\Domain\\User`
- `php artisan make:model Domain/User`

app folder:

```
app
 |    
 +-- App
 |
 |    
 +-- Domain
 |
 |    
 +-- Http
```

composer file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/App/",
      "Domain\\": "app/Domain/",
      "Http\\": "app/Http/",
      "Support\\": "app/Support/"
    },
```

**UPDATE**

`php artisan make:model ../Domain/User` solved the problem for model. I have stil the problem with a controller `php artisan make:controller ../Http/UserController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need to create a model outside the default location.

Artisan make commands will attempt to store the files in the standard location according to the command you running.

As an example, `php artisan make:model User` will create the model inside `app` directory (default directory for models). So assuming the desired destination for your model is one directory above and has the name Domain you can run the following command:

```
php artisan make:model ../Domain/User
```

Note that `../Domain/` is relative to the default location for that command.

For a controller, knowing the default directory is `app/http/Controller` and you want to generate a controller in `Domain/http/Controller` you can do it with the following command:

`php artisan make:controller ../../../Domain/Http/UserController`

Please note that this isn't usual and is not following the standards.

Hape that helps you with what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks this worked. The namespace was not correct but that is okay

Comment: Where do you need the controller to be created?

Comment: In my Http folder. I also tried to create one in my Domain folder but the file goes to the App folder.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.4 or later. You can create as below

```
  php artisan make:model "Domain\User"
```

> Use " (double quotes) or ' (single quotes) to create model

See here

[artisan make:model specify the directory and namespace?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/artisan-makemodel-specify-the-directory-and-namespace?page=1)

Comment: No that doesn't work for me. Still the same result.